# Resize Flash player problem on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, resize, flash

When i want to make my flasplayer( flowplayer ) resize to bigger or smaller with jquery , it does not work properly on internet explorer 
when i make it smaller i use this function

```
        ////Make player smaller 
 function createSmallPlayer() {



      flowplayer("player").hide().pause(); 

       // get handle to the embed element 


        $("#player").css({

                        // size 
            width:160*1.4,
            height:90*1.4,
            top :350,
            left  : 0           

          }) 

        var embed = $("#player :first"); 

        embed.css({ 
            // size 
            width:160*1.4 ,
            height:90*1.4,
            top :350,
            left  : 4



        }); 
         flowplayer("player").resume(); 

       }
```

and it works well on the internet explorer

but when i want to make its size previous style i use

```
 //Make player bigger 
 function createBigPlayer() {

        flowplayer("player").hide().pause();


         $("#player").css({

            // size 
            width :screen_width ,
            height:screen_height, 
            top   :35,
            left  : 0


          });


        // get handle to the embed element 
        var embed = $("#player :first");


        embed.attr("width","100%") ;
        embed.attr("height","100%") ;
        embed.removeAttr("style") ;

        flowplayer("player").resume();   

     }
```

this function does'nt work on IE  properly , it can't be resize, how ever after run this function when i click or resize IE window it works properly . I don't understand the problem .Sorry about my English :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research on this, too.  This appears to be a Flowplayer limitation.  You cannot resize the player DOM element once the player has been loaded.  Resizes can only occur in the OnBeforeLoad event; otherwise, the player will become unstable.